# For Scikit-Learn's RandomForestRegressor, can I specify a different n_jobs for predictions?

Tags: scikit-learn

[Scikit-Learn's RandomForestRegressor](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html) has an **`n_jobs`** instance attribute, that, from the documentation:

```
n_jobs : integer, optional (default=1)

    The number of jobs to run in parallel for both fit and predict. If 
    -1, then the number of jobs is set to the number of cores.
```

Training the Random Forest model with more than one core is obviously more performant than on a single core. But I have noticed that predictions are a lot slower (approximately 10 times slower) - this is probably because I am using `.predict()` on an observation-by-observation basis.

Therefore, I would like to train the random forest model on, say, 4 cores, but run the prediction on a single core. (The model is [pickled](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) and used in a separate process.)

Is it possible to configure the **`RandomForestRegressor()`** in this way?

Answer (score 1):

Oh sure you can, I use a similar strategy for stored-models.

Just set `<_aRFRegressorModel_>.n_jobs = 1` upon `pickle.load()`-ed, before using a `.predict()` method.

**Nota bene:**
the amount of work on `.predict()`-task is pretty "lightweight" if compared to `.fit()`, so in doubts, what are is core-motivation for tweaking this. Memory could be the issue, once large-scale forests may get a need to get scanned in `n_jobs`-"many" replicas ( which due to **`joblib`** nature re-instate all the python process-state into that many full-scale replicas ... and the [**new**, overhead-strict **Amdahl's Law re-fomulation shows**](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18374629/3) one, what a bad idea that was -- to pay a way more than finally earned ( performancewise ) ). This is not an issue for `.fit()`, where concurrent processes can well adjust the setup overheads ( in my models ~ 4:00:00+ hrs runtime per process ), but right due to this cost/benefit "imbalance", it could be a killer-factor for "lightweight"-`.predict()`, where not much work is to be done, so masking the process setup/termination costs cannot be done ( and you pay way more than get ).

BTW, do you `pickle.dump()` object(s) from the top-level namespace? I got issues if not and the stored object(s) did not reconstruct correctly. ( Spent ages on this issue )